# How to handle proxy connection timeout in pyrogram

Tags: python, proxy, python-3.6, pyrogram

I want to connect another proxy when i got timeout Error. but timeout error is not a raise so i don't know how to handle it.

This is my code :

```
from pyrogram import Client

app = Client(
"test",
api_id=235617,
api_hash='a50c4ad0c480c5665b47e2779e948b5c',
app_version ='1.0',
proxy=dict(hostname="5.8.18.84", port=33308),
) 


app.start()
```

Output :

`Error connecting to SOCKS5 proxy 5.8.18.84:33308: timed out`

Comment: Are you sure the server is up and reachable?

Comment: could [this](https://github.com/pyrogram/pyrogram/issues/201) be related to your issue?

Answer (score -1):

`@pyrogram.Client.on_disconnect`
Decorator for handling disconnections.

This does the same thing as `add_handler()` using the `DisconnectHandler`.